# Get Status from Scenario with Cucumber 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, cucumber

It looks like its no longer possible use

```
scenario.status
```

in Cucumber 2.0.0 to determine the status of a scenario (passed, failed, undefined, skipped).  It looks like it is possible to see if a scenario either passes or fails, but I'm also looking to see when steps are undefined or skipped.

Previously, in my code I would write the results to a DB in the After hook of the scenario, like so:

```
After do |scenario|
  @controller.post_results(scenario)
end
```

Inside of post results, I would call scenario.status to get the status.

Is this no longer possible to do with Cucumber 2.0.0? If it is, what is the new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Hooks.rb to get the status of scenario.

You can use

```
if scenario.failed?
    todo...
end
```

or

```
scenario.status
```

inside the hooks.rb.

Find more details here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

Comment: Thanks.  I should've posted, but there was a difference in the api at the time I originally posted this.  They've since added back the status method to the latest version of cucumber.